# How to implement a custom class similar to a std::vector

Tags: c++, overloading

My topic question is a little misleading, I dont want to implement a whole class like a std::vector but I want to be able to create a class called Container so I can declare it like so:

```
Container <unsigned int> c;
```

So is this how I overload the <> operator...

```
class Container
{
   private:
      Container() 
      {
         ...
      }

   public:
      void operator <>( unsigned int )
      {
         // what do I put here in the code?
         // maybe I call the private constructor...
         Container();
      }
};
```

Comment: What type of container do you have in mind?, an array, list, map, etc?, all those choices affect the nature of the final template

Answer (score 7):

There is no `operator <>`.  The `<>` denotes that `Container` is a *class template*.  You need syntax along the lines of:

```
template <typename T>
class Container
{
    ...
};
```

The best place to start is to find a good C++ book, but you could also try reading e.g. the [C++ FAQ page about templates](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html).

Answer (score 1):

You should learn more about templates.
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/

In a nutshell, what you want is:

```
template <class T>
class Container {
    ....
};
```